# Angular2 simplify BrowserDomAdapter usage

Tags: typescript, angular

In jQuery we got this:

```
$('.element').removeClass('active');
```

In A2 using `BrowserDomAdapter` we got this:

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter'
dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
this.dom.removeClass(this.dom.query('.mdl-layout__drawer-right'), 'active');
```

I am just thinking is it possible to simplify that by writing some sort of extension method so the above thing will became something like that :

```
this.dom('.element').removeClass('active');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're not supposed to use DomAdapter, see this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6231#issuecomment-195134102).

Answer (score 1):

`DOM` should be available by

```
import {DOM} from 'angular2/platform/common_dom';
```

and initialized with `BrowserDomAdapter` when the Angular application is run in the browser *UI thread*.

Currently there is an issue though
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904

Until this issue is fixed

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from '../platform/browser/browser_adapter';
...
BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();
```

should do the initialization of `DOM`

Comment: Just used `DOM.removeClass(DOM.query('.mdl-layout__drawer-right'), 'active');')` and got an error `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null`. Should I do more than just importing the `DOM` from `angular2/platform/common_dom` in order to make it work?

Comment: See the link at the end of my answer. It's supposed to work this way, but they introduced a bug recently.

Comment: eh. So shall I keep my `BrowserDomAdapter` usage case for now? It is working well for me until DOM will be fixed.

Comment: In the meantime calling ´BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();` should do the initialization of `DOM`.